# Youtube Live Stream Not Playing In a react-player version 2.9.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube, react-player

I integrated react-player to react.js website and it worked fine. But in a few days, it stopped working. and I also updated the plugin version to version 2.9.0. But it didn't work. And I noticed normal videos from youtube are playing fine **But youtube live streams are not playing.** below is the code I implement.

```
<ReactPlayer
        url={"https://youtu.be/5qap5aO4i9A"}
        config={{
          youtube: {
            playerVars: { showinfo: 1 },
          },
        }}
      />
```

[image: this is live stream URL]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-wescoff-my91x?file=/src/App.js)
(if doesn't work then try it on a private window) .It is playing live streams as well . This issue of yours is happening sometime . Please open it in another browser.

Comment: When I opened it in Microsoft edge it work fine and also I opened your sandbox in the chrome private window it also worked. Thank You